# XSLT for XML to XML quandary

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been assigned a new project to use an XSLT stylesheet to convert one XML document into another XML format.

I have spent the last four hours trawling through the archives on StackOverflow and elsewhere online to try to find out how to achieve the desired results, but nothing I can find points me the right direction.

Here's the original document format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PODOrderSheet_Main>
    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>
    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>
    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>
</PODOrderSheet_Main>
```

And here is how it needs to look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE estimate>
<estimate>
    <customer>LINFNC</customer>
    <jobType>5020</jobType>
    <JobParts>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>01</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>02</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>02</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>03</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>03</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
    </JobParts>
</estimate>
```

I'm able to copy over all the elements without any problems. Where I'm getting stuck is that I need only the first occurrence of the `customer` and `jobType` elements, but all of the included `JobParts` from the multiple `estimate` blocks, numbered correctly in the order they fall in the `jobPart` element.

I'd be very appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction on this project as I'm not getting anywhere on my own.

Comment: This is an example of grouping problem, so should not be too hard to solve. Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 though, as it makes a difference to how it is solved? Also, just to be clear, can a customer have different 'jobType' elements? In which case, would you want them grouped separately or together in the same group? Thanks!

Comment: The input example seems not to match the output. E.g. there is not `<jobPart>03</jobPart>` etc in your input.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the response. This is XSLT 1.0 and the jobType element will always be the one gathered from the first estimate block.

Comment: Yes the jobPart element needs to be updated to reflect the correct sequence number for however many JobPart blocks occur. This can be variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to me to be a grouping problem. As far as I can see you just need the first `customer` and `jobType` elements copied to the beginning of the output. Thereafter it's just a copy of all the `JobPart` elements. The `jobPart` (with a *small* `j` - nasty gotcha waiting there) elements get their own template to number them according the the containing `JobPart` elements in the source data.

This transform seems to do what you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/PODOrderSheet_Main">
        <estimate>
            <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/customer"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/jobType"/>
            <JobParts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="estimate/JobParts/JobPart"/>
            </JobParts>
        </estimate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="jobPart">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:number count="JobPart" level="any" format="01"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<estimate>
   <customer>LINFNC</customer>
   <jobType>5020</jobType>
   <JobParts>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>01</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>01</jobPart>
               <note>Rush Order</note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>02</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>02</jobPart>
               <note>Rush Order</note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>03</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>03</jobPart>
               <note>Rush Order</note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
   </JobParts>
</estimate>
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thanks for your help. Now I have to work on prepending and appending text strings to some of the copied values, but this gets me a long way towards my goal. Thanks again for taking the time to show me how to do this correctly.